# Combine multiple outputs into a pane

Tags: output-formatting, output, slideshows

**Probably unnecessary detail:** So here's what I'm envisioning. I have several outputs from different calculations (perhaps several ListAnimated tables of GraphicsGrids of plots). In one, I did all the calculations with x=0.13 and everything is a function of y. In a second output, I set y=0.36 and everything is a function of x. Now I want to produce a single box with perhaps tabs at the top that lets me switch between the different outputs.

In the limited case above, I could accomplish the whole thing with another nesting of ListAnimate, but what I'm really going for here is something more general. What I would like to be able to do is something like

"OutputTabbedPane[{%487, %488, %496}]"

and have it produce a single box or whatever that combined the (already computed, possibly long-time computations) outputs and let me click and cycle through them.

Pipe dream? Anyone know how to move in this direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is solved by TabView.

```
In[1]:= 5+4
Out[1]=9

In[2]:= AbsoluteTiming[Pause[3]; Plot[Sin[x],{x,-1,1}]
Out[2]= {3.013000, <plot of sin[x]>}

In[3]:= AbsoluteTiming[TabView[{%1,%2[[2]]}]]
Out[3]={0.,Tabbed pane with 9 and <plot of sin[x]>}
```

The timing bits are there to indicate that % calls the output without re-computing the possibly costly production of the output. The Tabbed output is nice and what I wanted here.

Edit: Manually labeling the tabs is done a bit unintuitively as rules.

```
TabView[{"label 1" -> %1, "label 2" -> %2[[2]]}]
```

changes the tab labels from the default {1,2} to {"label 1", "label 2"}